# assign Unique ID Jgrid Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

i am using Jgrid.i want when i add new row to the table each time it assign the new id to that row.

I am adding the row using

```
var AddNewRow = function(id){
                      var datarow = {Consultant:"",Role:"",Task:"",SDate:"",EDate:"",
                                       Deliverables:"",Complete:""};

                      var lastsel2 = i+1;
                      //debugger;
                      var su=jQuery("#test").addRowData(lastsel2, datarow, "last") ;
//                  if (su) { 
//                          jQuery('#test').editRow(lastsel2,true); 
//                                            
//                     
//                           }  


                      };
```

**And my complete code is....**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
     <!--<script type="text/javascript">

     var check=\$retrivexml;
      alert(check);
      </script>-->
    <link href="../../Content/css/Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/css/Style/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"
        type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/css/Style/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css"
        media="screen" />
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../Content/css/Style/jqModal.css" />-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../Content/css/Style/datePicker.css" />-->
    <!--<link href="../../Content/css/Test/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
    <!--<link href="../../Content/css/Test/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/celledit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/JsonXml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.import.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.base.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/js/Jgrid js/grid.formedit.js"></script> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(document).ready( function() {

      var i=3;  
     var grid = jQuery("#test");
            var MyExportToXml = function (grid) {
                var dataFromGrid = {row: grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data') };
                var xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>\n<rows>\n' +
                              xmlJsonClass.json2xml (dataFromGrid, '\t') + '</rows>';
                alert(xmldata);
            };


    var AddNewRow = function(id){
                      var datarow = {Consultant:"",Role:"",Task:"",SDate:"",EDate:"",
                                       Deliverables:"",Complete:""};

                      var lastsel2 = i+1;
                      //debugger;
                      var su=jQuery("#test").addRowData(lastsel2, datarow, "last") ;
//                  if (su) { 
//                          jQuery('#test').editRow(lastsel2,true); 
//                                            
//                     
//                           }  


                      };

     var lastsel3;
     jQuery("#test").jqGrid({
        url:'/Content/xml/user.xml',
        //url: $!retrivexml,
     datatype: "xml",
        colNames:['Consultant','Project Role', 'Task', 'Start Date','End Date','Deliverables','Complete'],
        colModel:[
         {name:'Consultant',index:'Consultant', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"K:Kin;R:Rajesh;R:Renee;S:Sandeep"}},
         {name:'Role',index:'Role', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
         {name:'Task',index:'Task', width:80, align:"right",editable:true},
         {name:'SDate',index:'SDate', width:90,editable:true},
         {name:'EDate',index:'EDate', width:90,editable:true},
         {name:'Deliverables',index:'Deliverables', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true,edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"25"}},
         {name:'Complete',index:'Complete', width:60, editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Complete:Incomplete"}}  
        ],


        rowNum:10,
        //rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: '#pagediv',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Project Planning",
     forceFit : false,
     cellEdit: true,
     editurl:'clientArray',
     cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
     height: "100%",

     ondblClickRow: function(id, iRow, iCol, e) {alert(iRow);}, 

     afterEditCell: function (id,name,val,iRow,iCol){     

        if(name=='SDate') {
       jQuery("#"+iRow+"_SDate","#test").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});

      }

     if(name=='EDate') {
       jQuery("#"+iRow+"_EDate","#test").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
      }
     },


    });
    jQuery("#test").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagediv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}).navButtonAdd('#pagediv', { caption:"New", buttonicon :'ui-icon-circle-plus', title: "Add New Row",
       onClickButton: function() {
           AddNewRow (grid);
       }
    });


    $("#export").click(function(){
                MyExportToXml (grid);
            });


      });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        <div align="center">
            <div id="pagediv">
            </div>
            <table id="test" align="center">
            </table>
            <input type="BUTTON" id="export" value="Export" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having of a counter in the scope of `jQuery(document).ready` and incrementing of it on every row add will work of cause. What is your question?

Comment: i want to access the last row id and the add 1 to that and assign to new row.     i.e-- New Row= Last row ID + 1;

Comment: You welcome! By the way if you write a comments to a question or an answer you should begin it with @Oleg then I will see a "post" for me (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using..

i count  all the row in grid and then add 1 to the count..

```
onClickButton: function() {
    var last = jQuery('#test').jqGrid('getGridParam','records'); 
    AddNewRow (last);
}

var AddNewRow = function(id){

    var datarow = {Consultant:"",Role:"",Task:"",SDate:"",EDate:"",
                   Deliverables:"",Complete:""};

    var lastsel2 = parseInt(id) + 1;

    var su=jQuery("#test").addRowData(lastsel2, datarow, "last") ;

};
```

Comment: It can work or not work depends on the values of `id` attributes inside of `/Content/xml/user.xml` and not depend of the count of rows in the table. Moreover if you allow user to remove a row then this algorithm could follow to double IDs. If you use integers as the IDs you could get all current IDs with respect of `getDataIDs`, find the maximum value and then use the max value + 1 for the new ID.

Comment: How can i use that getDataIDs property ?? Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to me mostly OK. The only potential problem which you can have with IDs is the possible conflict with IDs from `/Content/xml/user.xml`. You should be careful and not include integer IDs grater as 3 in the `/Content/xml/user.xml`.

Some more remarks to you code. I find personally not good to use variable with the name `lastsel2` in the context which has nothing with selection. The usage of variable with the name `i` in the scope of `jQuery(document).ready` (so the variable will be almost global because it will be seen everywhere) not very nice. A later modification of your code could occasionally reset the value of `i`.

Moreover I recommend you always verify you HTML code in a HTML Validator like http://validator.w3.org and verify your JavaScript code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will help you to find some problems in your code like

```
newDom.loadXML('<?xml version="1.0"?><rows><page>1</page><total>1</total><records>'+
               + entries.length + '</records></rows>');
```

('+' will be used twice: on the end of one line and at the beginning of the first one) or unused variables like `groupingView` inside of `gridComplete` functions. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) could help you to make your code more robust.

HTML Validator show you other errors in your XHTML code which could follow that in other browser version as you used for testing your Web application could work incorrect:

1) `runat` in unknown attribute for the `<head>` element in `"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`.  So you should replace `<head runat="server">` to `<head>`

2) To have no XHTML validation errors you should place the JavaScript code inside of `//<![CDATA[` `//]]>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  /* you can place your code here */
//]]>
</script>
```

3) Replace `<input type="BUTTON" ...>` to `<input type="button"  ...>` because XHTML is case sensitive.

4) Add mandatory attribute `action=""` to your `<form>` to follow `"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`. You can also replace `<form>` to `<fieldset>` if you not really want to use a form submitting.

5) Include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` inside of the `<head>` element.

6) Include `<tr><td /></tr>` inside of `<table>` to follow `"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`